# Converting a date from string to object in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo

I following this course on PHP and I'm really lost on this bit. The point is to be able to manipulate the date using a class.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    // Create a class called user

    class User {

        protected $dates = [
            'created',
        ];
        // This is supposed to convert my dates from a string to an object
        public function __construct() {
            foreach($this->$dates AS $date) {
                $property = $this->{$date};
                $this->{$date} = new DateTime($property);
            }
        }
        // Adding a public function that will be available outsite of the class
        public function getFullName() {
            return "{$this->firstname} {$this->lastname}";
        }
    }

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pdo', 'root', '');

    $req = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    $req->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');

    echo '<pre>', var_dump($req->fetch()), '</pre>';
    die();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>PDO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php while($user = $req->fetch()): ?>
            <div class="user">
                <h4><?php echo $user->getFullName(); ?></h4>
                <p>Registered on <?php echo $user->created->format('d M Y'); ?></p> <!-- does not work -->
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I load my page, I have three errors:

> Notice:  Undefined variable: dates in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Side-Projects/Courses/PHP:SQL/Learn
>   PHP Programming From Scratch/04 - PHP Data Object (PDO)/51 - User
>   class date/index.php on line 13
>
> Notice:  Undefined property: User::$ in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Side-Projects/Courses/PHP:SQL/Learn
>   PHP Programming From Scratch/04 - PHP Data Object (PDO)/51 - User
>   class date/index.php on line 13
>
> Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Side-Projects/Courses/PHP:SQL/Learn
>   PHP Programming From Scratch/04 - PHP Data Object (PDO)/51 - User
>   class date/index.php on line 13

Can someone help me understand how I can fix this? Thanks you in advance :)

Comment: There's a comma behind created that shouldn't be there? `created',`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - Shouldn't be an issue, PHP permits that

Comment: @Mark - Doesn't it create another entry in the array? An empty one, or NULL, in this case?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - Nope, and a lot of devs do put that trailing comma in "just because".... [demo](https://3v4l.org/6Qs0Z)

Comment: @Mark - Ok, my mistake. I'll have to test that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($this->$dates AS $date)
```

should be

```
foreach($this->dates AS $date)
```

Otherwise you're trying to use the `$dates` as a variable variable

Answer (score 0):

you have tow issues

**first** `$this->$dates` should be `$this->dates` , **second** `AS` should be lower case `as`

change this

```
foreach($this->$dates AS $date) {
```

to this

```
foreach($this->dates as $date) {
```

Comment: AS or as work the same. This hasn't introduce any problems in my other programs. $this->dates was the solution; thanks a lot!